# MySQL : How to remove string from column

Tags: mysql, trim, undo, concatenation

Very simple 
I have a column of string like that :

```
 abc1
 abc2
 abc3
 abc4
 abc5
```

I need to remove 'abc' from this column and keep only the number on the right, so column would have only the number like :

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

I thought about smth like that but it doesn't work

```
update table2
-> set col1 = case when 'abc1' then 1
-> else end;
```

I know how to concat text, I don't know how to undo it... Help please ^^;

Comment: Your example shows all the strings of the same length.  Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@McArthey already hinted at it, but this is easy to do when the "abc" is consistently "abc" (i.e. the length doesn't change.)

Amongst the various [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) is one in particular: [`RIGHT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right). This allows you to select a fixed number of characters from a string. e.g.

```
SELECT RIGHT('abc3',1) -- Results in "3"
SELECT RIGHT('abc3',2) -- Results in "c3"
```

Coupled with the [`LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) function, you can conclude the numbers are anything past the 3rd character. i.e.

```
SELECT RIGHT('abc3',LENGTH('abc3')-3) -- Results in "3"
```

Obviously I'm using hard strings (`'abc3'`), but these can easily be replaced with column names.

The caveat here is that these all are based on fixed length letter prefixes. The more variable (changing) the "abc" in your example is, the harder picking the numeric value out of the column becomes.

Comment: That was the first link I supplied in my answer. ;-) But thank you.

Comment: Lol sorry didn't follow it.  I'll delete mine heh

Comment: abc never change, but the numbers go from 1 to 30.

Comment: btw I'm not trying to select, but I need to modify the content of that column.. T.T

Comment: In that case I would use SUBSTR(column, 4) to grab all characters following 'abc'

Answer (score 1):

If these are single digit values you could use

```
select right(column,1) ...
```

You may also find the [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html) docs useful if it is more complex.

If you are trying to modify the column you will have to take the values separately and then concatenate them back together.  It's difficult to give a precise answer since I don't know what you're trying to accomplish but you could do something with SUBSTR to grab the separate values.

Get 'abc': SUBSTR(column, 1,3)

Get digits: SUBSTR(column, 4)